# Do motion blur shutter curves work correctly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, motion-blur

I have some problems understanding the motion blur shutter curve. I am near to the point to report a bug, actually ...

What I have done:

- use any mesh or the default cube, animate it to move in any direction
- go to the middle of the animation (the speed should be max there)
- enable motion blur (cycles)
- set the shutter curve to an extreme like from bottom left to top right

Now when you render the image, you will see ... well ... I can't tell from the image in which direction the cube is moving. Whatever I set the curve to, I can't tell the direction from a single image. Shouldn't that be obvious? Maybe I misunderstood that functionality.

This is an example of a moving cube with such a shutter curve
[image: in which direction does this cube move?]

I can supply the blend file, if needed.

To clarify what I expected: I expected a (nearly) sharp cube with some trails to the side it is coming from.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the way they always are...I've never seen it any differently.

Comment: You have to adjust your expectations :-)

Check any photo or movie still with motion blur, and you'll find that it looks exactly as the image you showed, with only one exception: when the camera is tracking the object.

Comment: In that case: What is the shutter curve actually used for? I was thinking it would allow you to set a somewhat focus on one frame while blending others a bit in.
I am looking for something like this: https://vvvv.org/sites/default/files/imagecache/large/Motion%20Blur%20Thumbnail.jpg

Comment: I think the idea is you can create just what you want, or at least near to it...
http://adaptivesamples.com/2015/11/16/cycles-custom-motion-blur-curves/

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with the shutter curve and it actually works like you expected. I have a Picture here showing tests with different shutter curves:

[image]

The white diagramm shows the curve I used for that render. As Object I took the default cube and made it glowing white on black background. I think the main trick to achive the effect that you want is to increase the shutter time to at least 1 (I used 1 for my renders) but that depends on the speeds of your objects in your scene.